# how to create a function that goes after another function with this method (function1(params).function2(params)) in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

how can I make this possible?

```
function _(element) {
    var el = document.querySelector(element);
    return el;
}

function colorize(color) {
    this.style.color = color;
}

_("#myElement").colorize("#f0f0f0");
```

that this code first gets the element and then changes its text color.
How to make sth like this?????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_("#myElement")` returns an instance of [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). You can add `colorize` property to `Element.prototype`. Now, all objects of type `Element` will be able to call it:

```js
function _(element) {
    var el = document.querySelector(element);
    return el;
}

function colorize(color) {
    this.style.color = color;
}

Object.assign(Element.prototype, { colorize })

_("#redText").colorize("red");
_("#greenText").colorize("green");
```

```html
<span id="redText">Red</span>
<span id="greenText">Green</span>
```

It's a bit more verbose but prototypes are usually extended using `Object.defineProperty` so that they are not enumerated as a property:

```
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'colorize', {
  value: colorize
})
```

Comment: if I change the querySelector to querySelectorAll and get an array how can I define that property for Array??

Comment: @MohammadMostafaDastjerdi `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`. So, add `colorize` to `NodeList.prototype`. And inside `colorize` function, loop through the elements and update the `style`. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/5qu62vcf/