# Is it possible create custom functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is it possible in Javascript to create custom functions like `focus ()` or `removeAttribute ()` and call it with `document.getElementById("id")`. I don't know if this could be done when inheriting from `htmlElement`.
Does someone have an idea how?

My idea is to call the function like this:

```
document.getElementById("id").customFunction();
```

Comment: You'd have to add methods to `HTMLElement.prototype` ... of course it's possible, it's just not recommended

Comment: I have answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62345915

Answer (score 0):

```js
//first sets the value creating a function or using a existing one
HTMLElement.prototype.showInnerHTML = function() {
  return this.innerHTML; //you can use any element inside this HTML element
}

var logInnerHTML = () => {
  console.log(document.querySelector("p").showInnerHTML());
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to log my innerHTML :)</p>
<button onclick="logInnerHTML()">Click me!</button>
```